# Retrieve the last changed revision respecting ancestry

Tags: svn

**I want to get the most recent SVN revision where a given file's content changed. I want this
information regardless of whether the file has been moved or copied. I would like to get this revision, to compare it to a "last reviewed" revision from my peer review system.**

For most files, `svn info` will give a "Last Changed Rev" with the desired
revision. This works within tags and branches as well, as long as the tag or
branch was created by copying the entire directory.

But some files have been copied or renamed, not using a full directory copy. On
these files, even if no changes to the file content occurred, the "Last Changed
Rev" from `svn info` reflects the revision where the copy or rename happened.
Unlike `svn diff` or `svn log`, I do not see any command-line flags to allow
following history.

I thought to extract the revision text shown by `svn info` and use `svn log -v`
on it, to get the copy-from path on files which were renamed or copied. Then I
could use `svn info` on the "from" path and revision as before.

But, as far as I can tell, `svn log` does not show when a file was copied and
also *modified* in the same commit. The log looks the same between an unmodified
copy-with-history, and a copy-with-history that is also modified.

`svn diff --notice-ancestry` can show the changes that happened during a copy.
so I can use this to show whether any changes happened or not during the copy.
`svn log --diff` sadly does not support `--notice-ancestry`, so that's a 3rd
command to use.

To sum up, I've come up with the following procedure, which I think
will work, but is WAY to complicated for my tastes:

```
 1. `svn info` to find last changed revision for each file
 2. `svn log -v -r` on that revision of that file to see what changed
   a. If change was a modification, this is the revision I want
   b. If change was an "add" action with no "from", this is the revision I want
   c. If change was an "add" action with a "from", continue to step (3)
 3. `svn diff -c` on the same revision found in (1)
   a. if there are no differences, start over at step (1) using the "from" path
      and revision found in (2c)
   b. if there are differences, this is the revision I want
```

Is there an easier way to do this? This will take a fairly complicated
script to accomplish what intuitively should be a very easy task.